# About electrostatic induction

Tags: electrostatics, charge

when we approach a charged rod (+) to a neutral metal rod ( not touching) a number of electrons to that side ( lets call it side B) negating the effect of the introduced electric field, reaching equilibrium.
But what about the electrons that where already on that side , will there presence affect the equilibrium , if some electrons ( those where already at side B before the electric field is introduced) disappeared what would happen to the equilibrium?
Forgive me if some of my ideas are faulty , i am new to the world of physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot say for sure as to where *each and every* electron will end up after attaining equilibrium, primariliy because the electrons are constantly moving about in the lattice.

It is kind of like trying to determine the exact position of every gas molecule after you compress the gas by a certain amount. The problem is that a gas molecule's motion is pretty random, so you cannot say for sure where that molecule will end up.

Similarly, in attaining the equilibrium, some electrons might end up at completely random places. But we can surely say that there will be more electrons on side B, than positive ions, because a net (-) charge will develop on side B. We can also determine how the electrons will arrange themselves, if we know the field of the charged rod.

Comment: well, i asked a friend and he said to me that the movement of electrons are random and because they are so many the one that moves from say side B will soon be replaced by another one, but my question was , lets say that side B already contained 20 electrons and needed 10 more to negate the effect of electric field and reach equilibrium , if we pretend they don't move , are those 20 essential to maintain equilibrium?

Comment: Those 20 electrons won't stay there by themselves right? They will need a metal atom (which is positive in charge without that electron) to support that electron. So electrostatically, this positive and negative charge together will have no effect, whatsoever, even on the equilibrium.

Comment: i think i got it, my friend told me that all electrons are exactly alike ,so if region B has an induced (-) charge because of the 20 free moving electrons already there and 10 new free moving electrons introduced to reach equilibrium , if 1 electron just magically disappeared and re-appeared in region A (the other side of the metal rod) , it will break the equilibrium , it doesn't matter either it was from the original 20 or the new 10 electrons. Does that seem right? Sorry, to bother you but just bear me a little , i am still in grade 9.

Comment: Yes that electron *magically teleporting* so far across will break the equilibrium. But it will be very quickly re-established too, by some other electron taking its place.